# Is there something like a map function in puppet?

Tags: puppet

[Any suggestions on a better title are welcome]

For better or worse, I currently have a data structure like so (yaml)

```
servers:
  server1.example.com:
    private_ip: 10.0.0.1
    public_ip: 22.33.44.1
  server2.example.com:
    private_ip: 10.0.0.2
    public_ip: 22.33.44.2
global_roles:
  nagios: 
    - server1
    - server2
```

I can pull that into puppet and do things like:

```
$nagios_monitor = $global_roles['nagios'][0]
$private_ip["${nagios_monitor}.example.com"]['private_ip']
```

What I want is a way to get an array of the private IPs for all listed nagios servers.  Is there a good way to do this with my existing data structure?

If the data structure needs to be changed, for this to work nicely, suggestions on a good way to present this data to puppet are also welcome.  I suspect such a change would make life generally easier, but there's a fair bit of existing code that would need to changed, and I really wouldn't want any mis-steps.

Comment: What version of Puppet are you running?

Comment: I've got multiple versions in use at present, but version 3.8 is the main target just now.  Upgrade to 4.x will follow down the track though, so it would be interesting to know any options that adds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a map function in puppet.
https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#map

Something like this might be what you want to do:

```
$nagios_servers = $global_roles['nagios']
$ip_addresses = $nagios_servers.map |$server| { $private_ip["${server}.example.com"]['private_ip'] }
```

It requires the future parser on 3.8 and is automatically included as of 4.0.